# Adding binary log to existing mysql server

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a fairly large (~50m rows) database on a single Centos server. I want to set up replication but the existing database has no binary logs.

Is there a way to retrospectively add binary logs so that the data can be replicated?

If not, I assume the only method is to dump the database with mysqldump and then import it into a freshly installed server which has binary logs enabled and then use that new server as the new master - any issues with this? Do I need to export/import the data with any particular flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to retrospectively add binary logs so that the data can be replicated?

Yes. Although it requires a server restart you can upgrade a single MySQL server to a Master in a replication cluster at any point in time.

The steps are pretty well documented in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-configuration.html

In essence, you upgrade your single MySQL to a master by starting to collect binary logs. Once binary logging has started you can create an initial export from the running master to populate the slaves with. Run `mysqldump` with the  `--master-data=1` option. That option will allow the slave to identify at which point the export was created on the master.

Once importing that export has completed the slave can then use the `master-data` to query  the master to replay any and all transactions from the binary logs on the master that occurred since the moment  the mysqldump export was created.

Comment: Thanks for that. Quick follow-up question..

I exported the data from server A and imported into B. Server A needed to be rebuilt so I then freshly installed a new server A and attempted to set up replication to pull the data back from B->A. 

'show slave status' on A shows a 'table xxx.xxx does not exist' error. Shouldn't the creation of this table be present in the binary logs on B? (and thus be replicated on A?)

Comment: Oh, maybe it's because it's trying to use row-based replication..?

Comment: (I later realised it's nothing to do with the binary log format, it's because the mysqldump output included lines to temporarily disable the binlog... Doh..)